# Second button is not working. Problem with Sequence of the IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue with the buttons.
The second button is not working whereas the first button is working fine.

I have embedded two snippets.

- Snippet 1 shows an error with the second button.
- Snippet 2 with no error.

**Q: What is the issue?**

I am using three IDs for my buttons following the index, which are, `#downloadbutton`, `#download`, `#timer`.

The issue is with the Sequence of these IDs in the `HTML` of the button.

If the first button IDs are `#downloadbutton0`, `#download0`, `#timer0`, and the second button IDs are `#downloadbutton2`, `#download2`, `#timer2`, the second button does not work.

> (Please see the Snippet 1)

And if these IDs are in sequence like `#downloadbutton0`, `#download0`, `#timer0` and `#downloadbutton1`, `#download1`, `#timer1`, both the buttons work fine.

> (Please see the Snippet 2)

**Q: What do I want?**

I have used these buttons in all my posts which are more than 150 and It will take lots of time to amend each and every post.

I am looking for something that can enable the buttons to work even if they are not in sequence, without changing HTML.

I will be very thankful.

- **Snippet 1**

```js
//<![CDATA[
document.querySelectorAll(".download_button").forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var timeleft = 45;

    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1() {
      document.getElementById('download' + index).style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("timer" + index).innerHTML = "Wait " + timeleft + "";

      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("timer" + index).innerHTML = ""
        window.open(document.querySelector('#downloadbutton' + index + ' a').href, '_self');
        document.getElementById('download' + index).style.display = "";
      }
      timeleft -= 1;
    }, 1000);
  });
})
//]]>
```

```css
.download_button {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 195px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button-1 {
  background: #f12711;
}
  
.button-2 {
  background: #fe8c00;
}

.button-3 {
  background: #0575E6;
}

.download_button:hover {
  background: #000000;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#download0, #download1, #download2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#download0:hover, #download1:hover, #download2:hover {
  background: #a3a3a3;
  color: #000000;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#timer0, #timer1, #timer2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #3d3d3d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
  
.button-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-center">
  <div id="downloadbutton0" style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="download_button button-1">
      <div class="title">1st Button</div>
      <div class="after-title">
        <div id="download0">DOWNLOAD</div>
        <a
          href="https://www.google.com"
        ></a>
      </div>
      <div id="timer0"></div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="downloadbutton2" style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="download_button button-3">
      <div class="title">2nd Button</div>
      <div class="after-title">
        <div id="download2">DOWNLOAD</div>
        <a
          href="https://www.google.com"
        ></a>
      </div>
      <div id="timer2"></div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

- **Snippet 2**

```js
//<![CDATA[
document.querySelectorAll(".download_button").forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var timeleft = 45;

    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1() {
      document.getElementById('download' + index).style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("timer" + index).innerHTML = "Wait " + timeleft + "";

      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("timer" + index).innerHTML = ""
        window.open(document.querySelector('#downloadbutton' + index + ' a').href, '_self');
        document.getElementById('download' + index).style.display = "";
      }
      timeleft -= 1;
    }, 1000);
  });
})
//]]>
```

```css
.download_button {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 195px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button-1 {
  background: #f12711;
}
  
.button-2 {
  background: #fe8c00;
}

.button-3 {
  background: #0575E6;
}

.download_button:hover {
  background: #000000;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#download0, #download1, #download2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#download0:hover, #download1:hover, #download2:hover {
  background: #a3a3a3;
  color: #000000;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#timer0, #timer1, #timer2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #3d3d3d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
  
.button-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-center">
  <div id="downloadbutton0" style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="download_button button-1">
      <div class="title">1st Button</div>
      <div class="after-title">
        <div id="download0">DOWNLOAD</div>
        <a
          href="https://www.google.com"
        ></a>
      </div>
      <div id="timer0"></div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="downloadbutton1" style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="download_button button-3">
      <div class="title">2nd Button</div>
      <div class="after-title">
        <div id="download1">DOWNLOAD</div>
        <a
          href="https://www.google.com"
        ></a>
      </div>
      <div id="timer1"></div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

querySelector isn't only applied to document, it also applies to any element and queries it's children.

I removed the all ids, and used attributes instead without any indexes.

```js
//<![CDATA[
document.querySelectorAll(".download_button").forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var timeleft = 45;

    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1() {
      item.querySelector('[data-download]').style.display = "none";
      item.querySelector('[data-timer]').innerHTML = "Wait " + timeleft + "";

      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        item.querySelector('[data-timer]').innerHTML = ""
        window.open(item.querySelector('a').href, '_self');
        item.querySelector('[data-download]').style.display = "";
      }
      timeleft -= 1;
    }, 1000);
  });
})
//]]>
```

```css
.download_button {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 195px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button-1 {
  background: #f12711;
}
  
.button-2 {
  background: #fe8c00;
}

.button-3 {
  background: #0575E6;
}

.download_button:hover {
  background: #000000;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#download0, #download1, #download2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#download0:hover, #download1:hover, #download2:hover {
  background: #a3a3a3;
  color: #000000;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#timer0, #timer1, #timer2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #3d3d3d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
  
.button-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-center">
  <div data-button style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="download_button button-1">
      <div class="title">1st Button</div>
      <div class="after-title">
        <div data-download>DOWNLOAD</div>
        <a
          href="https://www.google.com"
        ></a>
      </div>
      <div data-timer></div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div data-button style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="download_button button-3">
      <div class="title">2nd Button</div>
      <div class="after-title">
        <div data-download>DOWNLOAD</div>
        <a
          href="https://www.google.com"
        ></a>
      </div>
      <div data-timer></div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

***UPDATE***

This update to your first Snippet to make it wihout making edit in the HTML, just by modify the index.

```js
//<![CDATA[
document.querySelectorAll(".download_button").forEach(function(item, index) {
  index !== 0 && (index = 2);
  console.log(index)
  item.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var timeleft = 45;

    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function function1() {
      document.getElementById('download' + index).style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("timer" + index).innerHTML = "Wait " + timeleft + "";

      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("timer" + index).innerHTML = ""
        window.open(document.querySelector('#downloadbutton' + index + ' a').href, '_self');
        document.getElementById('download' + index).style.display = "";
      }
      timeleft -= 1;
    }, 1000);
  });
})
//]]>
```

```css
.download_button {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 195px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.4s;
  outline: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button-1 {
  background: #f12711;
}
  
.button-2 {
  background: #fe8c00;
}

.button-3 {
  background: #0575E6;
}

.download_button:hover {
  background: #000000;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#download0, #download1, #download2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#download0:hover, #download1:hover, #download2:hover {
  background: #a3a3a3;
  color: #000000;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#timer0, #timer1, #timer2 {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #3d3d3d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
  
.button-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-center">
  <div id="downloadbutton0" style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="download_button button-1">
      <div class="title">1st Button</div>
      <div class="after-title">
        <div id="download0">DOWNLOAD</div>
        <a
          href="https://www.google.com"
        ></a>
      </div>
      <div id="timer0"></div>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="downloadbutton2" style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="download_button button-3">
      <div class="title">2nd Button</div>
      <div class="after-title">
        <div id="download2">DOWNLOAD</div>
        <a
          href="https://www.google.com"
        ></a>
      </div>
      <div id="timer2"></div>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Mina, Thanks for the comment but that's not I wanted.
I have told you, I do not want to change the HTML. Just want to amend the script.

Comment: You are welcome, but you already have a working example, so what is the problem? I thought you complaining about indexing the id of the elements.

Comment: Indexing the ids as you did is a bad practice, also styling by id isn't good too, you need to make some refractory of your code.

Comment: Bro I have used these two buttons with [#downloadbutton0, #download0, #timer0, and the second button IDs are #downloadbutton2, #download2, #timer2] in 150+ posts. Currently with this sequence, 2nd button is not working but I want it to work with the same sequence of the index 0 and 2.

Comment: So, if you have only these two buttons, check if the index === 0, then get the ids with index 0, if the index === 1, then get ids with index 2

Comment: If you will see the Snippet 2, If index is 0 for first button and index 1 button, both the buttons will work. But if index is 0 for the first button but index 2 is for second button, the second button will not work (as shown in snippet 1). I want it to work even if the index is 0 for first button and 2 for second button. 

If it won't be possible, I have to edit each and every post on my blog replacing index 2 to index 1.

Comment: No actually, there is one more button which is used in some posts with the index 1. That's the middle button.

Comment: I just update my answer, and make your first snippet work with with first button with index 0 and the second button with index 2

Comment: Hey Mina, It somehow work but not as i wanted. If there is one more button in the middle with index 1, How it can be work too? Please update it for three buttons.

Comment: It should be work irrespective of index 0, 1, 2 or Index 0, 2. If a post have three buttons with index 0, 1, 2, It should work. Even if a post have two buttons with index 0 and 2 only, It should also be worked.

Comment: No, sorry it can't magically be done this way, you need make changes in HTML.